# RethinkDB max file size attachments (BLOB)

Tags: rethinkdb, rethinkdb-python, rethinkdb-javascript

I found in documentation that RethinkDB can store Binary Files (BLOBs).

This is great !

I have an ECM application and need to store 50.000.000 of files. ( from 8K until 1GB ).

I need to know what is the max file size in RethinkDB ?
Will be some problem with performance ?
How RethinkDB will store these files on disk ?
Is there any overhead or memory issues ?

Any Help is Appreciate.

Comment: I wouldn't store the files in the DB but on a distributed FS like AFS, GFS, HDFS and just store its path in the DB. As long as ONLY your code handles the save, update and delete of the files, it's the best IMO. I always found dirty to store files in a DB.

Answer (score 2):

You can get around the 64Mb limit by using libraries like [ReGrid](https://github.com/internalfx/regrid)

ReGrid is a method of storing large files inside a RethinkDB database.

It's similar to GridFS but designed for RethinkDB.

Comment: I just found that the [C# RethinkDB driver](https://github.com/bchavez/RethinkDb.Driver/wiki/ReGrid-File-Storage) has built in support for ReGrid! And it seems very well documented too.

Answer (score 1):

According to http://www.rethinkdb.com/limitations/

> - While there is no hard limit on the size of a single document, there is a recommended limit of 16MB for memory performance reasons.
> - The maximum size of a JSON query is 64M.

Comment: But Is this recommendation for attachments (BLOBs) ?

Comment: Yes. RethinkDB stores binary data as part of the document, not separately.